# UITextView Delegate shouldChangeTextInRange (or any over) doesn't get called

Tags: uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I need to track changes in my UITextView method (actianly for limiting number of lines), but none of UITextViewDelegate methods are being called when editing in UITextView begins. Not even `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;`

I dont know what Im doing wrong

I added UITextViewDelegate method to header file like that:

`@interface PirmasViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, MFMa......`

And I put any methods for tracking changes in my implementation file:

`- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{NSLog(@"something changed");}`

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString*)aText{`
`NSLog(@"something changed");`
`return YES;`
}`

but no rezults.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing one line of code:

```
UITextViewFieldName.delegate = self;
```